# Simulating typing with jQuery, pausing or lengthening the setInterval function

Tags: jquery, animation, settimeout

So I want to make a jQuery app where text is being animated on the screen to look as if someone is typing something. I've achieved this in its most simplest form.

HTML

```
<p></p>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = $('p');
    p.text('');


    window.setInterval(function(){
        inc(p);
    }, 100);

});

var i = 0;

function inc(p)
{

    var text = "Hey... This is just a test";
    p.append(text.charAt(i));
    i++;
}
```

What I want to know is, how would I maybe after "Hey ..." tell the function to stop for 2 seconds? Or however many I want it to.

I had an idea but it's very inefficient and "crappy", and that is to add as many whitespaces as it would take to print nothing for 2 seconds, then replace the string with everything before the whitespace and continue appending.

This is terrible and I'd like a better way of doing it. Could anyone please give me any suggestions? And is setInterval the correct function to use or should I utilize setTimeout?

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/0puzwygf/) a fiddle of my code.

I appreciate any help or suggestions, thank you very much.

Comment: i don't get you, you want to reload your  function after 2 second?

Comment: So, let's say I have a string "Hey... This is just a test", I want to be able to do something like, ""Hey... [pause:2s] This is just a test", and then I can run an if statement before appending anything, and check with regex how many seconds to pause for, and after that time is passed, I continue appending @shayanypn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a better way to do this but I'm posting my working answer.

I have replaced you `setInterval` by a `setTimeout` inside your `inc` function. So it is now recursive.

And you can change the interval when a certain character is typed by checking the index.

**EDIT :**

After OP comment I changed my answer so you can set delay inside the text using embraces.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = $('p');
    p.text('');

    inc(p);
});

var i = 0;
var j = 0;

function inc(p) {
  var interval = 0.1;
  var text = "Hey... {2} This is a {1} test";
  var array = text.split(/[\{\}]/); // Split on embraces
  
  if (i < array.length) {
    p.append(array[i].charAt(j));
    
    if (j == array[i].length -1 && typeof array[i + 1] !== "undefined") {
      interval = array[i + 1];
      i += 2;
      j = 0;
    }
    
    j++;
    setTimeout(function () { inc(p); }, interval*1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Comment: I posted this comment on the answer above, but I have the same concern so I will paste it here " 
I guess if I have more than one waitpoint, I'd make an array, but I don't want to index every single time I want to pause, anyway I could do this by checking a special string in the string, like "Hey.. [pause:2s] this is a test" and when it reads '[' it can see how many seconds I told it to wait? " I hope that makes sense, so I might want to have this "Hey... [pause:2s] this is a test. [pause:4s] Hello everyone" and pause for 2s and 4s respectively

Comment: @SamirChahine I edited my code. You should now be able to do *"Hey... {2} test"* to make a 2 seconds pause. Tell me if that is ok for you.

Comment: It works on "run code snippet" but when I add it to the fiddle it doesn't show? https://jsfiddle.net/0puzwygf/5/

Comment: Looks like jsfiddle is having some trouble... It works well on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqMBPR)

Comment: @SamirChahine It was a pleasure. Please note that the first character after the closing embraces is removed (I don't know why... I'm not a regex god so that may be a clue). Be sure to had a space after the closing embraces just so you keep your text.

Answer (score 0):

try this, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shayanypn/0puzwygf/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $p = $('p');
    $p.text('');
    waitFun($p);  
});
var timer;
var wait_time=2000;
var wait_point=7;
var count=0;
function waitFun($p){
  clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
  var text = "Hey... This is just a test";
    $p.append(text.charAt(count));
    count++;
  if(text.length == count) {return false} //avoid of infinte loop

  if(count == wait_point){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        waitFun($p);
    },wait_time);
  }else{
  waitFun($p);
  }

  },100);

}
```

Comment: I guess if I have more than one waitpoint, I'd make an array, but I don't want to index every single time I want to pause, anyway I could do this by checking a special string in the string, like "Hey.. [pause:2s] this is a test" and when it reads '[' it can see how many seconds I told it to wait?